# Wine - Getting odd errors when running Desktop View

Tags: wine, games, error-handling, executable

Recently I re-installed Wine and am working on installing some old games. The game installed and runs, but I noticed that in the terminal I get the following:

```
00a0:err:rpc:I_RpcReceive we got fault packet with status 0x1c010003
```

Also, when I ran wine control and when I opened the application to calibrate my bluetooth controller, I got the following:

```
wine: L"C:\\windows\\system32\\joy.cpl" is a dll, not an executable
```

While it doesn't seem to affect any actual processes so far, I would like to understand what is causing wine to generate these errors just in case it does cause a problem down the line.
Happy to provide additional information, but am still a beginner with linux/ubuntu.

```
    Wine Info:
    wine-6.0.3 (Ubuntu 6.0.3~repack-1)

    Ubuntu info:
    Distributor ID: Ubuntu
    Description: Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
    Release: 22.04
    Codename: jammy
```